# Where is load presets option in Terminal preferences?

Tags: terminal, macos

I have El Captain installed. I want use external color scheme and for that I am following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1S5J39-93I) but I don't find Color Presets option in terminal. My El Captain's terminal looks very different from Yosemite's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person in that video is using iTerm2, a free third party terminal replacement. You can get it here:

http://iterm2.com/

Comment: So, is it fully functional as terminal?

Comment: Yes, you can do everything you do in Terminal and more with iTerm2